# Can I claim UK ancestry for a grandfather born in a Crown territory (Rhodesia)?

Tags: united-kingdom

My grandfather was born in 1921 in Southern Rhodesia while it was a foreign territory and the Crown exercised extraterritorial jurisdiction. My father was born in 1954 in Rhodesia while it was a Commonwealth country. I was born in Rhodesia in 1978 while it was an independent Commonwealth country. My grandfather's mother was born in Birmingham, England in 1890. As Rhodesia was part of the Crown when my grandfather was born, would this allow me to apply for an ancestral visa on "UK born" grandparent?

I'm currently living in South Africa. I'm a South African passport holder (obtained via descent from my maternal grandfather).

Comment: Possibly related https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13812/by-what-means-can-someone-with-british-great-grandparents-enter-the-uk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [By what means can someone with British great-grandparents enter the UK?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13812/by-what-means-can-someone-with-british-great-grandparents-enter-the-uk)

Comment: @Rebecca have you had a look at the linked question above? I very much doubt this case will qualify because Rhodesia being part of the Crown is not the same as being part of the UK (The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland is a distinct area and does not encompass anywhere else)